# Pivot or zip a seq<seq<'a>> in F#

Tags: f#, functional-programming, pivot, sequence

Let's say I have a sequence of sequences, e.g.

```
{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}
```

What is the best way to pivot or zip this sequence so I instead have,

```
{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3}
```

Is there a comprehensible way of doing so without resorting to manipulation of the underlying `IEnumerator<_>` type?

To clarify, these are `seq<seq<int>>` objects. Each sequences (both internal and external) can have any number of items.

Comment: So do you want to do a matrix transposition or group by an element - this is not very clear.  An example for a longer input would be good.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I write a ZipN-like function in F#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770441/how-do-i-write-a-zipn-like-function-in-f)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're going for a solution which is semantically Seq, you're going to have to stay lazy all the time.

```
let zip seq = seq
            |> Seq.collect(fun s -> s |> Seq.mapi(fun i e -> (i, e))) //wrap with index
            |> Seq.groupBy(fst) //group by index
            |> Seq.map(fun (i, s) -> s |> Seq.map snd) //unwrap
```

Test:

```
let seq =  Enumerable.Repeat((seq [1; 2; 3]), 3) //don't want to while(true) yield. bleh.
printfn "%A" (zip seq)
```

Output:

```
seq [seq [1; 1; 1]; seq [2; 2; 2]; seq [3; 3; 3]]
```

Comment: while this will work, Seq.groupBy is not lazy and will fully evaluate its input sequences once the first element is requested from Seq.groupBy

Comment: Is `Seq.mapi (fun i e -> (i, e))` the same as `Seq.indexed` ? (https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-seqmodule.html#indexed) -- EDIT: yes - see Joshua answer

Answer (score 1):

This seems very inelegant but it gets the right answer:

```
(seq [(1, 2, 3); (1, 2, 3); (1, 2, 3);]) 
|> Seq.fold (fun (sa,sb,sc) (a,b,c) ->a::sa,b::sb,c::sc) ([],[],[]) 
|> fun (a,b,c) -> a::b::c::[]
```

Comment: It looks promising, but how do I convert seq<seq<int>> to seq<int*int*int> to use this method?

Comment: OP's question requires the solution to operate on a sequence of sequences of variable length, and not a sequence of n-tuples.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like matrix transposition.

```
let data =
    seq [
        seq [1; 2; 3]
        seq [1; 2; 3]
        seq [1; 2; 3]
    ]

let rec transpose = function
    | (_::_)::_ as M -> List.map List.head M :: transpose (List.map List.tail M)
    | _ -> []

// I don't claim it is very elegant, but no doubt it is readable
let result =
    data
    |> List.ofSeq
    |> List.map List.ofSeq
    |> transpose
    |> Seq.ofList
    |> Seq.map Seq.ofList
```

Alternatively, you may adopt the same method for `seq`, thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1757340/974789) for an elegant Active pattern:

```
let (|SeqEmpty|SeqCons|) (xs: 'a seq) =
  if Seq.isEmpty xs then SeqEmpty
  else SeqCons(Seq.head xs, Seq.skip 1 xs)

let rec transposeSeq = function
    | SeqCons(SeqCons(_,_),_) as M ->
        Seq.append
            (Seq.singleton (Seq.map Seq.head M))
            (transposeSeq (Seq.map (Seq.skip 1) M))
    | _ -> Seq.empty

let resultSeq = data |> transposeSeq
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10849803/974789) for technical details and two references: to **PowerPack**'s `Microsoft.FSharp.Math.Matrix` and yet another method involving **mutable data**.

Comment: This evaluates all the sequences eagerly though. `Seq.ofList` does nothing but cast the list to `seq<'t>`, so there isn't much meaning in having the signature as `seq<seq<'t>>`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same answer as @Asti, just cleaned up a little:

```
[[1;2;3]; [1;2;3]; [1;2;3]] 
    |> Seq.collect Seq.indexed 
    |> Seq.groupBy fst 
    |> Seq.map (snd >> Seq.map snd);;
```