# How do I write effectively to a file in F#?

Tags: f#

I want to generate large xml files for testing purpose but the code I ended up with is really slow, the time grows exponentially with the number of rows I write to the file. Th example below shows that it takes milliseconds to write 100 rows, but it takes over 20 seconds to write 1000 rows (on my machine). I really can't figured out what is making this slow, since I think that writing 1000 rows shouldn't take that long. Also, writing 200 rows takes about 4 times as long as writing 100 rows which is not good. To run the code you might want to change the path for the `StreamWriter`.

```
open System.IO
open System.Diagnostics

let xmlSeq = Seq.initInfinite (fun index -> sprintf "<author><name>name%d</name><age>%d</age><books><book>book%d</book></books></author>" index index index)

let createFile (seq: string seq) numberToTake fileName =
    use streamWriter = new StreamWriter("C:\\tmp\\FSharpXmlTest\\FSharpXmlTest\\" + fileName, false)
    streamWriter.WriteLine("<startTag>")
    let rec internalWriter (seq: string seq) (sw:StreamWriter) i (endTag:string) =
        match i with
        | 0 -> (sw.WriteLine(Seq.head seq);
            sw.WriteLine(endTag))
        | _ -> (sw.WriteLine(Seq.head seq);
            internalWriter (Seq.skip 1 seq) sw (i-1) endTag)
    internalWriter seq streamWriter numberToTake "</startTag>"

let funcTimer fn =
    let stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew()
    printfn "Timing started"
    fn()
    stopWatch.Stop()
    printfn "Time elased: %A" stopWatch.Elapsed


(funcTimer (fun () -> createFile xmlSeq 100 "file100.xml"))
(funcTimer (fun () -> createFile xmlSeq 1000 "file1000.xml"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with the following solution:

```
namespace FSharpBasics

module Program2 =

    open System
    open System.IO
    open System.Diagnostics

    let seqTest count : seq<string> =
        let template = "<author>\
                    <name>Name {0}</name>\
                    <age>{0}</age>\
                    <books>\
                    <book>Book {0}</book>\
                    </books>\
                    </author>"

        let row (i: int) =
            String.Format (template, i)

        seq {
            yield "<authors>"
            for x in [ 1..count ] do
                yield row x
            yield "</authors>"
        }

    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main argv =
        printfn "File will be written now"

        let stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew()
        File.WriteAllLines (@".\test.xml", seqTest 10000) |> ignore
        stopwatch.Stop()

        printf "Ended, took %f seconds" stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds

        System.Console.ReadKey() |> ignore

        0
```

It takes less than 90 milliseconds on my laptop to create a well-formed *test.xml* file with 10,000 authors.

Answer (score 6):

You observed a quadratic behaviour `O(n^2)` on manipulating sequences. When you call `Seq.skip`, a brand new sequence will be created, so you implicitly traverse the remaining part. More detailed explanation could be found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/1306267.

In this example, you don't need to decompose sequences. Replacing your inner function by:

```
let internalWriter (seq: string seq) (sw:StreamWriter) i (endTag:string) =
    for node in Seq.take i seq do
        sw.WriteLine(node)
    sw.WriteLine(endTag)
```

I can write 10000 rows in fraction of a second.

You can refactor further by remove this inner function and copy its body to the parent function.

As the link above mentioned, if you ever need decomposing sequences, `LazyList` should be better to use.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that I was creating a new sequence each time. However, I should replace the inner function, I could just remove the inner function and add the for loop to the outer function.

Answer (score 5):

[pad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/634025/pad) in his answer has pointed to the cause of slowdown. Another idiomatic approach might be instead of infinite sequence generating sequence of needed length with [Seq.unfold](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340363.aspx), which makes the code really trivial:

```
let xmlSeq n = Seq.unfold (fun i ->
    if i = 0 then None
    else Some((sprintf "<author><name>name%d</name><age>%d</age><books><book>book%d</book></books></author>" i i i), i - 1)) n

let createFile seqLen fileName =
    use streamWriter = new StreamWriter("C:\\tmp\\FSharpXmlTest\\" + fileName, false)
    streamWriter.WriteLine("<startTag>")
    seqLen |> xmlSeq |> Seq.iter streamWriter.WriteLine
    streamWriter.WriteLine("</startTag>")

(funcTimer (fun () -> createFile  10000 "file10000.xml"))
```

Generating 10000 elements takes around 500ms on my laptop.

Comment: Thank you for filling in other useful information. The other answers is more targeted my question but you presented some really useful extra information.